# Applying dataframe value to a dataframe when using unstack()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There seems to be a lot out there on this, but I cannot find what I need. I am using unstack() to create a DataFrame that I can plot the items of.

Starting DataFrame Sample:

```
Date        word    tf_idf
2015-01-02  grout   0.0016774129439329863
2015-01-02  rhrsw   0.0015957287173067212
2015-01-02  county  0.001501862322171032
2015-01-02  limestone 0.001501862322171032
2015-01-02  lgt       0.0014079959270353424
```

A better example as word tf_idf values change over time (that is what I need to plot):

```
Date word tf_idf
2015-01-02 grout 0.0016774129439329863
2015-01-02 rhrsw 0.0015957287173067212
2015-01-17 bfn0eq 0.0026125536132961145
2015-01-17 rhrsw 0.001473748192115757
```

Using tutorials online, I can sort of get this to work via:

```py
plotFrame = plotDf.groupby(['Date','word']).count()['tf_idf'].unstack()
```

Yields:

```
      word    word2   word3
date    1       nan     nan
date2   nan     1        1
date3   nan     nan      1
```

However, this gives me the count of words. I need to get the actual `tf_idf` value of that specific word. I have tried:

```py
plotFrame=plotDf.groupby(['Date','word']).apply(plotDf.loc['Index'].at['tf_idf'])['tf_idf'].unstack()
and

plotFrame = plotDf.groupby(['Date','word']).apply(plotDf.loc['tf_idf'])['tf_idf'].unstack()

and

plotFrame = plotDf.groupby(['Date','word']).apply(plotDf.at['tf_idf'])['tf_idf'].unstack()
```

Along with a few other `apply() .loc` combos with no other output than Series not hashable/Key/Numpy array is not callable type errors.

How can I retrieve the value of `tf_idf` at a specific word and apply it to my new DataFrame?

I want:

```
      word       word2   word3
date    0.012      nan     nan
date2   nan     0.019     0.03
date3   nan     nan       0.01
```

Comment: Can you share at least part of the DataFrame?

Comment: See the edit jj

Comment: I meant in a format that is easy to use, the goal is to be able to copy/paste it and have it working ASAP.

Comment: Also, can you explain what the data is for, why you need it in that particular format?

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to get it in and what format you are wanting. I need it in that format so I can plot each word,value pair over time

Comment: Ah, there are multiple values for each word? That wasn't evident from the data above.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. Sometimes the word ```tf_idf``` value can increase/decrease or become nan. I want to see/plot these changes over time

Comment: What are you using to plot? Won't a simply `groupby()` work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204499/discussion-between-sam-dean-and-alexander-cecile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Use pivot:

```py
plotDf.pivot(index='Date', columns='word', values='tf_idf').plot(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
```

Here is my approach in this, it doesn't look perfect but solves your question :

> How can I retrieve the value of tf_idf at a specific word and apply it
>   to my new DataFrame?

```
today = datetime.now()
today = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
c = {'Date': today, 'word':['grout','rhrsw','county','limestone','lgt'],"SITEID": ['SQN','BFN','BFN','BFN','BFN'],
    'tf_idf': [0.0016774129439329863,0.0015957287173067212,0.001501862322171032,0.001501862322171032,0.0014079959270353424]}
dframe = pd.DataFrame(data = c)
df = pd.DataFrame(dframe.set_index('tf_idf').stack())
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]